# Use only date from TIMESTAMP SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I use a select command to obtain "created_at". This is the date the row was created. The result of the command is 2018-07-29 15:29:57. How do I only show the date and remove the time.

**Current Result:** 2018-07-29 15:29:57

**Desired Result:** 2018-07-29

```
SELECT treatment_log.created_at
FROM treatment_log
LEFT JOIN customers
    ON treatment_log.treatment_fk = customers.id
WHERE treatment_log.created_at = 
        (
            SELECT MAX(created_at)
            FROM treatment_log
            WHERE treatment_fk = ?
        )
    AND customers.id = ?
```

**How do I changed my current code?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi Below is the solution

Sql Server :

```
SELECT CAST(treatment_log.created_at as DATE)
FROM treatment_log
LEFT JOIN customers
    ON treatment_log.treatment_fk = customers.id
WHERE treatment_log.created_at = 
        (
            SELECT MAX(created_at)
            FROM treatment_log
            WHERE treatment_fk = ?
        )
    AND customers.id = ?
```

for my SQL

```
SELECT DATE(treatment_log.created_at)
FROM treatment_log
LEFT JOIN customers
    ON treatment_log.treatment_fk = customers.id
WHERE treatment_log.created_at = 
        (
            SELECT MAX(created_at)
            FROM treatment_log
            WHERE treatment_fk = ?
        )
    AND customers.id = ?
```

Answer (score 0):

just.use date funtion

`select date（now（））`will return todays date not time

in sub query 1st convert in date then take max  select  `max`（date （created_at））

Comment: Where you suggest I add this function, in my code? Could you please add it into my code.

Comment: joe in place of your date column that is created_at im from mobile so i just share you key point i will care after 10min

Answer (score 0):

You can simply try this

```
    SELECT SUBSTRING(MAX(created_at),0,10)
    FROM treatment_log
    WHERE treatment_fk = ?
```

or

```
    SELECT MAX(DATE_FORMAT(created_at,'yyyy-mm-dd'))
    FROM treatment_log
    WHERE treatment_fk = ?
```